# AnguarJS - call multiple functions in one $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to call two functions in one `$watch`?
I have one function which is binded to two values and I want to bind second function to only second value. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function to wrap both.

```
$scope.$watch('whatever', function() {
  firstFunction();
  secondFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Group the values into an object. Then wrap the all the callbacks into a single listener function.

```
scope.$watch('obj', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue.a !== oldValue.a) { doAchange() }
  if (newValue.b !== oldValue.b) { doBchange() }
}, true);
```